# Tool to compare directories and files depending on specific given conditions

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a tool that combines the power of several other existing programs as there are `diff` (and all GUIs: `meld`, `diffuse`, `kompare`), `fslint`, `rsync`, `unison`.

I want to have the possibility to create complex conditions like "look at filenames but ignore filesize and permissions" or "look at filesize but ignore changes up to 100kB" or "compare directory structure (whole path of a file)" or of course "compare by hash sum"

Is there such a tool out there? If not, what workflow would take the least effort to get this done using existing tools?

I am fairly capable of scripting but I hate it to be honest. I don't like it, to create a script for every little task I have to do.

I hope you can help me here.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this (commercial, pay for) tool:

Beyond Compare 3

Beyond Compare is a powerful time-saving utility for comparing files and folders. Use it to manage source code, keep folders in sync, compare program output, and validate copies of your data.

Beyond Compare can create a snapshot of a live directory structure, and compare it against the live copy at a later date. Beyond Compare helps you analyze differences in detail and carefully reconcile them.

It commands a wide range of file and text operations, as well as script commands for automating tasks.

[Download Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php)

Comment: I tested it now and unfortunatly there aren't enough options too. There are some nice options like ignoring case or just compare size and ignore differenes of timestamps but it is still not enough. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @dAnjou, you can make feature request for useful capabilities. Also, since your last comment much time has passed. May be it now has the lacked functionality.